# Creating a simple gui program using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Don't understand why this simple code doesn't work. Sorry in advance for my stupidity. I have such errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python/coding/simple_gui", line 28, in <module>
     app=Application(root)
  File "C:/python coding/simple_gui", line 9, in __init__
    self.create_widgets()
  File "C:/python coding/simple_gui", line 14, in create_widgets
    self.bttnl.grid()
AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'bttnl'
```

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize frame"""
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create 3 useless buttons"""
        #first one
        self.bttn1=Button(self, text ="I do nothing!")
        self.bttnl.grid()
        #second button
        self.bttn2 = Button(self)
        self.bttn2.grid()
        self.bttn2.configure(text ="Me too!")
        #third one
        self.bttn3 = Button(self)
        self.bttn3.grid()
        self.bttn3["text"]="And me also!"

root=Tk()
#alter window
root.title("The simpliest gui")
root.geometry("200x100")
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have a typo in the code `bttnl` instead of `bttn1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. You wrote **bttnl** instead of **bttn1** in line 14.

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Initialize frame"""
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
    def create_widgets(self):
        """Create 3 useless buttons"""
        #first one
        self.bttn1=Button(self, text ="I do nothing!")
        self.bttn1.grid()
        #second button
        self.bttn2 = Button(self)
        self.bttn2.grid()
        self.bttn2.configure(text ="Me too!")
        #third one
        self.bttn3 = Button(self)
        self.bttn3.grid()
        self.bttn3["text"]="And me also!"

root=Tk()
#alter window
root.title("The simpliest gui")
root.geometry("200x100")
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could've easily been a comment.

Comment: @Inkblot It's a solution, why should it be in a comment?

Comment: Because it's not much of a change to warrant an answer but it isn't really that big of a deal